# Запятые в уточняющих обстоятельствах места

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите! Как здесь правильно расставить знаки препинания?

Я училась в институте им. Н. Крупской на отделении технических библиотек со специализацией технический перевод.

Родилась я в Ленинграде, в семье интеллигенции.

По распределению я попала в НИИЭТУ в отдел технической информации…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я расставил бы знаки так:
Я училась в институте им. Н. Крупской, на отделении технических библиотек со специализацией "технический перевод".

Родилась я в Ленинграде, в семье служащих.

По распределению я попала в НИИЭТУ - в отдел технической информации…

Comment: А не нужна ли запятая перед "со специализацией"?

Comment: Нет, не нужна: отделение со специализацией